# Will a condenser lens improve contrast under low magnification bright field imaging (10x)?

Tags: optics, microscopy

I have a 10x 0.28NA air lens that I am using to image inhomogeneities a semi-opaque gel cylinder - 500um in length and 100um in thickness, using white bright field light.

Will a condenser lens have a significant impact on contrast at such a low magnification as compared to a diffuser and light source alone?  Why are condenser lenses typically only used at much higher magnification?

Comment: Would this be a better question for Photography SE?